# Bootstrap radio buttons do not check when collapsing an accordian

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've tried a lot of things to try and get this to work. All I want to do is "when checking a radio button the accordion content will close and open accordingly and the button will 'check'". I have got this to work but the button wont appear checked - please see for more detailed example http://jsfiddle.net/cmE5L

```
            <label class="radio inline">
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked>Credit / debit card</label>

            <label class="radio inline">
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2" data-toggle="collapse" href="#card">PayPal / Maestro</label>

            <div class="accordion">
                <div id="card" class="accordion-body collapse in">
                    <p>CONTENT</p>  
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your `.on('click'...)` into `.on('change'...)` (Line 217):

```
$(document).on('change.collapse.data-api', '[data-toggle=collapse]',
    function (e) {
        var $this = $(this), href
          , target = $this.attr('data-target')
            || e.preventDefault()
            || (href = $this.attr('href')) && href.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]+$)/, '')
            //strip for ie7
          , option = $(target).data('collapse') ? 'toggle' : $this.data()
        $this[$(target).hasClass('in') ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('collapsed')
        $(target).collapse(option)
});
```

**[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cmE5L/2/)**.

**UPDATE**

If you have other elements like `<a...>` that shares this function with radio buttons, in this case, what you have to do is to check if you are going to use it for links, radio buttons or whatever element you are gona use it.

**UPDATE 2**

My suggestion to use same function with diferent elements:

```
function expand(e) {
    var $this = $(this), href, target = $this.attr('data-target')
        || e.preventDefault()
        || (href = $this.attr('href')) && href.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]+$)/, '')
    //strip for ie7
      , option = $(target).data('collapse') ? 'toggle' : $this.data()
    $this[$(target).hasClass('in') ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('collapsed')
    $(target).collapse(option)
}

$(document).on('click.collapse.data-api', 'a[data-toggle=collapse]', expand);

$(document).on('change.collapse.data-api',
    'input[type="radio"][data-toggle=collapse]', expand);
```

**[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jwkbv/)**

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked a treat.

Comment: Actually, I do have a problem with this... I do have other events using the 'collapse' that don't work with 'on.change' such as <p><a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#manualaddress">Enter address manually</a></p>

Comment: @TomRudge Could you add all that does not work in a JsFiddle, please? I will take a look to it and see if I can give you a solution.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3ByDN/ "Enter address manually" does not expand now, but the other part works great - thanks to yours truly!

Comment: @TomRudge I thought that your event was only for radio buttons. If your other clickeable elements have the same event and you use `onclick` event, why do you use `e.preventDefault()`? That's why never worked for radios, I've seen it now. Remove that and it will work for all. It didn't worked with links, because his state never changes and `onchange` event never fires.

Comment: Yes, I did try this, however removing e.preventDefault() allows me to click the checked radio button again this then "expands" the payment selection whereas the 'on.change' didn't let me do that.

Comment: @TomRudge Sorry I don't really understand you. Is it what you wanted? I mean... is your problem solved?

Comment: Thanks DaGLiMiOuX, problem solved, I just didnt want to be able to click the checked radio button again and it "re-open" the accordion it just closed.

Comment: @TomRudge You are welcome! To solve your problem, I would suggest you to check if it is a radio button that your method uses `'change'` and if it is an `<a...>` that uses a `'click'`.

Comment: The code you're asking @TomRudge to change is part of the core Bootstrap JavaScript code. I'd avoid that because it makes updating to new versions more difficult. The actual solution is much simpler. Use `data-target="#card"` instead of `href="#card"` on the radio inputs. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old one but the accepted answer is just wrong. While it works, the solution proposed is to change the core code within Bootstrap which you don't want to do if you can avoid it.

The actual problem is the invalid code in the example from the original poster. It is using an `href="#card"` on the radio input. This isn't valid html. Bootstrap assumes that when it sees a `data-toggle` attribute with an href that you'll be using it on a link and you don't want the browser's default action of navigating to the href so it prevents this.

When you put an href on the radio input Bootstrap prevents the default action which is selecting the radio. Use Bootstrap's alternate method of adding a `data-target="#card"` to the radio input and you won't get the preventDefault and everything will work as it should.

I've created an [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tinyfly/rcspz4t8/) with valid html that fixes the problems but the relevant code that fixes the issue is below

```
<label class="radio inline">
  <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#card"> Credit / debit card
</label>

<label class="radio inline">
  <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#card"> PayPal / Maestro
</label>

<div class="accordion">
   <div id="card" class="accordion-body collapse in">
     <p>CONTENT</p>  
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code was preventing the default action of the radio button when it was clicked.  I removed it from this segment of the code and it now works.

```
/* COLLAPSE DATA-API
 * ================= */
  $(document).on('click.collapse.data-api', '[data-toggle=collapse]', function (e) {
    var $this = $(this), href
      , target = $this.attr('data-target')
        //removed || e.preventDefault()
        || (href = $this.attr('href')) && href.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]+$)/, '') //strip for ie7
      , option = $(target).data('collapse') ? 'toggle' : $this.data()
    $this[$(target).hasClass('in') ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('collapsed')
    $(target).collapse(option)
  })
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/cmE5L/1/