# How to use Bootstrap accordion with a radio button list

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, radio-button, accordion

I am trying to build a UI that combines an HTML radio button list with the accordion functionality offered by Bootstrap's `collapse` component. The goal is that selecting any radio button also expands an accordion panel immediately below it.

[Here's a JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TimCoulter/VvyrC/) that demonstrates a partially working implementation. Unfortunately, although the accordion functionality works, the radio buttons do not get selected (apart from the initial selection, which subsequently never changes).

Please excuse the invalid HTML in my sample. I am aware that an `input` element doesn't have an `href` attribute, but I don't believe that this the cause of the problem.

I have seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16666597/168614) to a similar question, but I would prefer to avoid editing the Bootstrap code and hope there might be a purely declarative way of making this work.

Many thanks for your suggestions,
Tim

EDIT: For anyone else facing the same issue, this functionality works out-of-the-box in Bootstrap v3.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it to work with a little extra jQuery. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SchmalzyB/dpJXh/)

I'm sure there are more elegant ways of doing this. but it works.

```
$('#collapseOne').on('shown', function(){
    $('#radio1').prop('checked', true);
});

$('#collapseTwo').on('shown', function(){
    $('#radio2').prop('checked', true);
});

$('#collapseThree').on('shown', function(){
    $('#radio3').prop('checked', true);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I'm still curious whether there is a purely declarative solution to this but your solution does indeed work and it's good enough. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, however some side behaviour that's weird is that clicking on an enabled radio button will make the accordeon collapse again.

Answer (score 4):

The code below is slightly more elegant, but based on Schmalzy's answer.

This does not work any better, but does reduce down to one block of code for all of the accordion toggles.

I wanted to avoid updating the JS code if I added additional toggles.

```
$("[id^=collapse]").on('shown', function(){
    $(this).parents('.accordion-group').find('.accordion-toggle')
         .prop('checked', true);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is indeed the `href` attribute on the label. Use the `data-target` attribute on the label instead.

Bootstrap assumes valid html and that an href will be on an anchor tag. So it prevents the default action which is to follow the link and performs the collapse instead. In your case the default action of clicking on a label is to check the associated input. Bootstrap is preventing that.